# how do I upload images to iOS gallery?

Tags: appium

I have a test scenario where I need to select images from iOS gallery but there are only few native images. How do I upload the images to the gallery and then select image in my automation.
Framework - Python/Appium

didn't see any lead on the forums for iOS